# How can I specify an Arima in state space form correctly in R?

Tags: r, arima, state-space

I have tried to model an AR(2) model in state space form in R, but I am not sure if my code is correct.

```
fn <- function(var.param)  return( dlmModARMA(ar=as.vector(var.param[1:2])) )
```

Do I have to specify dV and sigma2 as well? If it is necessary, how would it work?

Comment: Perhaps you can provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I do not know how to provide my data but my question is only whether the function is correct for an AR(2) in state space form? ``` r
fn <- function(var.param)  return( dlmModARMA(ar=as.vector(var.param[1:2])) )
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>
 I have used the dlm package  and want to forecast the AR(2) in state space form but I am not sure if I specified the model correct. Do you need the data or more of the code?